# Erro System.OutOutMemory ao exportar excel c#

Tags: c#, exportação

Eu preciso exportar um relatório para excel em c#, mas quando uso esse código, é retornado a exceção `'System.OutOfMemory'` na linha: `wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Relatorio");` por conta do tamanho do excel (580mil linhas).

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    string db = Request.QueryString["DB"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
    string de = Request.QueryString["DB"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");


    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Relatorio");
    wb.Worksheet(1).Range("A1:O1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Gainsboro;
    wb.Worksheet(1).Range("A1:O1").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.DimGray;

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=InventoryReport___" + db + "___" +
                       de + "___" + DateTime.Now.Day + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" +
                       DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" +
                       DateTime.Now.Second + ".xlsx");

    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {

        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o tamanho do seu Datatable? Eu criei um teste aqui, com um datatable de 580.000 linhas e 8 colunas, sendo uma delas sempre uma string com 3KB de texto. Funciona normal, gerando um arquivo Excel de 40MB. Veja o código nesse gist: https://gist.github.com/marcusvx/22531eeed1d21226f6241f37687b2a89 . Se puder mostrar mais código referente ao datatable pode ajudar também.

Comment: A memória do seu computador ultrapassou os 95% ao realizar essa rotina.